Optional Stopping Theorem for martingales bounded except at the stopping time
One form of the Optional Stopping Theorem is as follows.  Let $X$ be a submartingale, $T$ a stopping time, and $a$ a constant such that for all $n$ we have $|X_{n \wedge T}| \le a$ almost surely; then $E[X_T] \le E[X_0]$.
What happens if we relax the last hypothesis to "$|X_{n \wedge (T-1)}| \le a$ almost surely"?  For example, if $T = \inf\{n : |X_n| > a\}$ then this condition is automatically satisfied, so it would be very convenient if the theorem still held.  I think it should not hold, but I cannot think of a counterexample.

I'm pretty sure this fails in continuous time, for instance $T$ may be the explosion time of a process.

My friend pointed out a simple counterexample: $X_0 = 0$, $$X_{n+1} = \begin{cases} X_n & \text{with probability $1/2$} \\ X_n - 2^n & \text{with probability $1/4$} \\ X_n + 2^n & \text{with probability $1/4$} \\ \end{cases}$$
and set $T = \inf\{n : |X_n| > 0\}$.  Then this satisfies the above conditions but $E[X_T]$ does not exist.
On the other hand, if $E[X_T]$ exists and is finite then the theorem holds, since we can bound $|X_{n \wedge T}| \le |X_T| + a$ so $X_{n \wedge T}$ is uniformly integrable.
